# Is my iPhone 6S Plus compromised?

Tags: wifi, mobile, bluetooth

Is it usual practice on an iPhone 6S Plus for the wifi and Bluetooth addresses to be identical except for the very last number? One ends in .44 and the other .45.

I've also had a lot of weird things go on with my phone and that is why I'm wondering if it's a security issue. I'm fairly new to iPhone and I apologize if what's going on with my phone is normal behavior.

Comment: Apple provides great support. Go to a Genius Bar and let them figure it out. Your phone provider may be able to help as well.

Comment: Thanks guys. As I'm a novice here, I appreciate the guidance (Rory) and the response from Neil. There are a lot of things happening with this phone that are odd. I have spoken with Apple, first a customer service rep, then he sent me to his superior, and from there, to a senior advisor. I would love to go to a Genious Bar, but the closest Apple Store is over 200 hundred miles away. My car broke down, so for now, I'm stuck. Anyway, thanks again for the help you were able to give me. TR

Comment: I don't know if this is the appropriate site, but I do have one other question please? What is StackOverflow and why do I have so many in my diagnostics? Some days I'll have 8 or 9 of them for that day. The CoreTime reports stopped and the Stack Overflows began on a daily basis. The CoreTime diagnostics stopped on December 30, 2015 and I haven't had one since? Again, I apologize if I'm out of bounds here, so to speak. And again, thank you for your kindness and patience with me as I learn the rules. Terri

Comment: A stack overflow just means that some software on your phone is broken. Perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is a better site.

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing to worry about, there's no reason to believe that you're compromised from just what you've stated.  Addresses are assigned by the chip manufacturer (and, the bluetooth and wifi are likely on the same chip), it's most likely just easier for the manufacturer to increment by 1 for each one.  The bluetooth/wifi addresses are also expected to be different.